# What is the difference between the projection onto the column space and projection onto row space?

Tags: linear-algebra

If I see a question that asks "find the projection a vector $b$ onto a matrix $A$" I would either solve by using $A^TA\hat x =A^Tb$ and then the projection would equal $A\hat x$,

and if the matrix $A$ was orthogonal then I would use $proj_bA = \frac{b \cdot q_1}{q_1 \cdot q_1}q_1 + ... + \frac{b \cdot q_k}{q_k \cdot q_k}q_k$ where $q_k$ represents the $k^{th}$ vector in matrix $A$.

My question is what if a question says find the projection of some vector $b$ onto the column/row space of matrix $A$?
What does this mean and what would I need to do differently to calculate it?

Comment: Projecting onto the row-space of $A$ is the same as projecting onto the column-space of $A^T$.

Comment: Solving $A^TA \hat x = A^Tb$ is "projective $b$ onto **the column-space of** the matrix $A$".  Strictly speaking, it is non-sense to say that you're 
"projecting a vector onto a matrix".

Comment: @Omnomnomnom so if I have to project onto the row space I would use $AA^T\hat x=Ab$?

Comment: Yep.${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> if the columns of matrix $A$ are linearly independent,
>   the projection of a vector, $b$, onto the column space of A can be computed
>   as
>
> $$P=A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$$

From [here](http://www.math.umn.edu/~rejto/4242/4242_2final_sol3.pdf).

[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)#Formulas) seems to say the same. It also says [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_and_column_spaces#Definition_2) that

> The column space of $A$ is equal to the row space of $A^T$.

I'm guessing that

> if the **rows** of matrix $A$ are linearly independent,
>   the projection of a vector, $b$, onto the **row** space of A can be computed
>   as
>
> $$P=A^T(AA^T)^{-1}A$$

Comment: Is there a way to compute this more efficiently? E.g. using some decomposition?

Comment: @Euler_Salter no idea. try asking as a new question and then link it here. i'm curious as well. Edit: oh is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4179797/computationally-efficient-way-to-compute-projection-matrix) it?