# Computationally efficient way to compute projection matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, projection-matrices

Is there some computationally efficient way of computing $(A^\top A)^{-1}$?
I would like to know this cause I want to compute the projection matrix
$$
P = A(A^\top A)^{-1} A^\top
$$
efficiently.

Comment: @MorganRodgers Not sure what your point is - here $A$ must be invertible because $A^\top A$ is invertible.

Comment: @MorganRodgers Right. I was assuming for no reason that $A$ is square (in which case what I said _does_ follow)\

Comment: @Euler_Salter I would bet that the downvotes are because you have asked a question with no context (e.g. motivation or attempts). If you need a more comprehensive list of of what constitutes helpful context for a question, see [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: @Euler_Salter Is there a reason that you need to be particularly "efficient" in your computation of $(A^TA)^{-1}$? Is this a computation on the computer or by hand? If this is a computation on the computer, then how large is $A$? With all that said, $A^TA$ will be symmetric and positive definite, so you might find the discussion on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40703042/2476977) to be interesting.

Comment: @BenGrossmann I will be using a computer. Essentially at a point on a manifold, I need to compute the projection matrix that will project a point onto the tangent space. In my particular case $A$ is basically a matrix whose columns are span the tangent space. I will need to do this projection many thousand times so I would like this to be very efficient

Comment: @Euler_Salter How large is $A$? That is, how many rows/columns?

Comment: Honestly it could be any size. But in practice it would have $n$ rows and $m$ columns with $n > m$

Comment: @Euler If you care about efficiency, then presumably you have some kind of "numerical experiment" in mind; otherwise, why would it matter how long it takes to find the inverse? For the purposes of this experiment, what is $m$? What is $n$? Is $n$ approximately $10$? $100$? $1000000$?

Comment: @Euler Also, if the purpose of finding the projection matrix is to project a single vector (i.e. to compute $Px$ for a specific vector $x$), then you might want to avoid computing the inverse at all. For instance, you could use the [conjugate gradient method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_gradient_method).

Comment: @BenGrossmann good point. At the moment I am working on toy examples with both $n$ and $m$ less than $10$, but this is just because they are toy examples. In practice it will depend on the problem at hand, but I would be happy for this to be efficient for hundreds of dimensions

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thank you. So the conjugate gradient method in this case would solve for $y$ this
$$
A (A^\top A)^{-1} A^\top  x = y \implies A^\top x = A^\top y ?
$$

Comment: @Euler_Salter I'm not quite sure what you're saying there; here's what I had in mind. Compute $y = A^Tx$. Then use the CG method to solve $(A^TA)z = y$ (so that $z = (A^TA)^{-1}A^Tx$). Then compute $Az$ to get $Px$.

Comment: Ooh that's smart

Comment: @Euler_Salter That said, Matlab is generally as good as it gets when it comes to matrix computations. It seems that entering `A*(A'*A)\(A'*x)` leads to solution [using the Cholesky decomposition](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html#bt42oms_head) for your case, so I suspect that for most usage cases that'll be "good enough".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm going to suggest an indirect method which, while slightly longer, is more accurate.

Suppose $A$ is $n\times m$ with $n > m$ has full column rank. As a rule of thumb, you can usually get away without computing with the matrix $A^\top A$ in matrix computations, and this is advisable if possible.

You can reformulate your goal as finding an orthonormal basis $Q\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ for the column space of $A$. One can then compute matrix-vector multiplications with the projection $\Pi_A = A(A^\top A)^{-1}A^\top = QQ^\top$ by $4mn$ operations by evaluation $\Pi_Ax = Q(Q^\top x)$.

The most efficient and accurate way to do this is by [QR factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition), which under the hood is implemented with Householder reflectors and is very accurate. You want to use economy QR factorization $A=QR$ which computes $Q\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ with orthonormal columns rather than full QR factorization $A = Q'R'$ which computes a full $n\times n$ matrix $Q'\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. In MATLAB, this is done by the call `[Q,~] = qr(A,0)`.

Let's see how this works. Note that $R$ is nonsingular. Thus,

$$
\Pi_A = A(A^\top A)^{-1}A^\top = QR(R^\top R)^{-1}R^\top Q^\top = QQ^\top,
$$

as promised.

If $A$ is rank-deficient (or approximately rank-deficient), you will want to use a SVD and threshold out small singular values to compute an orthonormal basis for the (approximate) column space. I can elaborate on this point in the comments if desired.

Why is this worth the hassle? Consider the following MATLAB example

```
>> Q_true = randn(10000,100); [Q_true,~] = qr(Q_true, 0);
>> A = Q_true * gallery('randsvd',100,1e10);
>> x = randn(10000,1);
>> tic; disp(norm(A*((A'*A)\(A'*x)) - Q_true*(Q_true'*x))); toc
Warning: Matrix is close to singular or badly scaled. Results may be inaccurate. RCOND =
1.095993e-20. 
 
     2.299635478974520e+01

Elapsed time is 0.003516 seconds.
>> tic; [Q,~] = qr(A,0); disp(norm(Q*(Q'*x) - Q_true*(Q_true'*x))); toc
     1.177844914088478e-06

Elapsed time is 0.021228 seconds.
```

The method based on QR factorization is like eight times slower, which isn't great. But the error for the QR-based method is ten million times smaller than for the $(A^\top A)^{-1}$ method!

If you can afford it and $A$ is even moderately ill-conditioned, the QR factorization method pays for its modestly increased cost with dramatically increased accuracy.

As Ben Grossmann suggests, iterative methods may be appropriate of $A$ is well-conditioned and $n$ and $m$ are both large.

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful! Do you have any resource to learn about this area of linear algebra? I took 2 linear algebra courses at university but honestly we skimmed very very briefly matrix decompositions and basically didn't really cover projections in depth.

Comment: @Euler_Salter The books by [Golub and Van Loan](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/cv/GVL4/golubandvanloan.htm), [Trefethan and Bau](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/trefethen/text.html), and [Demmel](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9781611971446?mobileUi=0) are all excellent. My personal philosophy about matrix computations is that they're kind of like cooking: there are a number of fundamental techniques (analogous to knife skills, boiling, braising, etc.) from which you can solve most problems. You get a lot of mileage out of LU, QR, eigenvalue problems, SVD, and conjugate gradient.

Comment: Thank you so much, will order one of those!

Comment: Let $A'$ be $A$ with an extra vector $a$ appended. Is there an efficient way to compute $\Pi_{A'}$ from $\Pi_A$? Something like the [matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma) or [Sherman–Morrison formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula)?

Comment: Question posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4553769/efficient-recomputation-of-row-space-projection-matrix-given-a-new-row-vector).